# Creating Python binding to cppcoro generator

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, c++-coroutine, cppcoro

I am trying to create a class in C++ with a generator method to run in Python, and I need the method to return lists of values. For coroutines I am using a maintained fork of [cppcoro](https://github.com/andreasbuhr/cppcoro).

Here's an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <experimental/random>
#include <cppcoro/generator.hpp>

class RandomVectorGenerator{
    int Range;
    int Limit;
public:
    RandomVectorGenerator(int range, int limit): Range(range), Limit(limit){}

    cppcoro::generator<std::vector<int>> get_random_vector(){
        for(int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) {

            int random_lenght = std::experimental::randint(0, Range);
            std::vector<int> random_vector;

            for (int i = 0; i < random_lenght; i++) {
                uint32_t random_value = std::experimental::randint(0, Range);
                random_vector.push_back(random_value);
            }
            co_yield random_vector;
        }
        co_return;
    }

};
```

Given `Range` and `Limit`, this class can generate up to `Limit` integer vectors, with 0 to `Range` values from 0 to `Range`.

Using it in C++ as follows:

```
int main() {
    RandomVectorGenerator generator = RandomVectorGenerator(5, 5);
    auto gen = generator.get_random_vector();
    auto iter = gen.begin();
    while (true) {
        std::vector<int> solution = *iter;
        for (int j = 0; j < solution.size(); j++) {
            std::cout << solution[j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        ++iter;
        if (iter == gen.end()) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As expected I might get an output as such

```
2 2 4 1 
0 5 2 

0 
2 4
```

If I bind the class and its' methods to python as follows:

```
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(random_vectors, m) {
    py::class_<RandomVectorGenerator>(m, "random_vectors")
    .def(py::init<int, int>())
    .def("__iter__", [](RandomVectorGenerator &generator) { 
        auto gen = generator.get_random_vector(); 
        return py::make_iterator(gen.begin(), gen.end()); 
        },
        py::keep_alive<0, 1>());
};
```

This binding compiles and creates an importable module. However, when I proceed to use the iterator,

```
from random_vectors import random_vectors

generator = random_vectors(5, 5)
iterator = iter(generator)

print(next(iterator))
```

Running the code above in a fresh kernel causes `next(iterator)` to raise `StopIteration`.

Runnning it after the first time gives output. The output lenght is of the expected range, but the values are all over the place, for example `[1661572905, 5, 1514791955, -1577772014]`

further more if I call `next(iterator)` again, the kernel silently crashes.

I can reproduce the behaviour on C++ side by modifying `int main()` as such:

```
int main() {
    RandomVectorGenerator generator = RandomVectorGenerator(5, 5);
    auto iter = generator.get_random_vector().begin();             //Here's a change
    while (true) {
        std::vector<int> solution = *iter;
        for (int j = 0; j < solution.size(); j++) {
            std::cout << solution[j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        ++iter;
        if (iter == generator.get_random_vector().end()) break;    //Also here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the same output as in python, but does not crash silently, it happens right at `++iter`, and the message is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

My guess is that the issue with the binding is that the `gen` object in the binding is created temporarily and does not remain after creation of the iterator. I tried changing the `py::keep_alive` arguments, but to no avail.

I am convinced that for this to work, the`begin()` and `end()` methdods have to be part of the whole class, just like it is in the pybind11 examples on iterators, but I can not define them just like in the examples, because the generator method has to first be initialized.

Thus my conclusion is that `RandomVectorGenerator` has to be derived from the cppcoro::generator, if that is right, how would I go about this?

Comment: Is there a guarantee that cppcoro routines are compatible with Python?  Both players have considerable state information, and I believe cppcoro will exploit multiple threads, which is an issue.

Comment: @TimRoberts No, there is no guarantee, in fact, there is very little I could find about coroutines and pybind. Multithreaded C++ shouldn't be an issue for `pybind11` as you can release and acquire Global Interpreter Lock.

Comment: You certainly don't want to call `get_random_vector` in each generation -- that will create a brand new generator, unrelated to the others.  I think you need to create the generator in your `__init__` and save it in the class state so you can refer to it in `__iter__`.  Right?

Comment: Excellent idea, managed to get it working. Had to also release the GIL before returning the iterator. Will post the answer today. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, the solution I got earlier ended up being broken. I am still going to describe it at the end of this answer for reference. It behaved in an interesting manner, very rarely, under seemingly normal conditions, it worked.

I had to resort to a workaround, the resulting python class does not have an `__iter__` method, but it's good enough because I can then create a children class on python side after compilation.

Solution is as follows:

```cpp
class RandomVectorGenerator{
    int Range;
    int Limit;
    cppcoro::generator<std::vector<int>> generator;
    cppcoro::detail::generator_iterator<std::vector<int> > iter;
    cppcoro::detail::generator_sentinel end;
public:
    RandomVectorGenerator(int range, int limit): Range(range), Limit(limit){}

    void make_generator(){
        generator = this->get_random_vector();
        iter = generator.begin();
        end = generator.end();
    }

    std::vector<int> get_next(){
        if (iter == end) throw py::stop_iteration("end reached");
        std::vector<int> vect = *iter;
        ++iter;
        return vect;
    }

    cppcoro::generator<std::vector<int>> get_random_vector(){
        for(int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) {
            int random_lenght = std::experimental::randint(0, Range);
            std::vector<int> random_vector;
            for (int i = 0; i < random_lenght; i++) {
                uint32_t random_value = std::experimental::randint(0, Range);
                random_vector.push_back(random_value);
            }
            co_yield random_vector;
        }
        co_return;
    }
};
```

What I've done is created a method which creates an iterator internally from the `cppcoro` generator (`make_generator`), which is then wrapped in an equivalent of `__next__` (`get_next`).

This class is then bound to python as such:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(random_vectors, m) {
    py::class_<RandomVectorGenerator>(m, "random_vectors")
    .def(py::init<int, int>())
    .def("make_generator", &RandomVectorGenerator::make_generator)
    .def("__next__", &RandomVectorGenerator::get_next);
};
```

Given that I am going to create a child class in python afterwards, binding `get_next` to `__next__` isn't strictly necessary, however, it *felt cute*. Note that nowhere do I have to release the GIL.

On Python side, I then utilize this bound class like so:

```py
from random_vectors import random_vectors

class generator(random_vectors):
    def __init__(self, Range, Limit):
        super().__init__(Range, Limit)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        self.make_generator()
        return self

for i in generator(5,5):
    print(i)
```

It works as expected, the solution just ends up somewhat hacky. However, the result is that I can now utilize C++ coroutines in python. Plus I was able to make this *work* for my more complex use case (Dancing Links), however it crashes for larger problems, so the quest is not complete, but it's something.

---

As for the broken solution. It was much more elegant that what I have above.

This was the solution:

```cpp
class RandomVectorGenerator{
    int Range;
    int Limit;
public:

    RandomVectorGenerator(int range, int limit): Range(range), Limit(limit){
        generator = this->get_random_vector();}

    cppcoro::generator<std::vector<int>> generator;

    cppcoro::generator<std::vector<int>> get_random_vector(){
        for(int i = 0; i < Limit; i++) {
            int random_lenght = std::experimental::randint(0, Range);
            std::vector<int> random_vector;
            for (int i = 0; i < random_lenght; i++) {
                uint32_t random_value = std::experimental::randint(0, Range);
                random_vector.push_back(random_value);
            }
            co_yield random_vector;
        }
        co_return;
    }
};
```

It is quite similar to the one above, but rather than creating a `__next__` I tried to create an `__iter__` with `pybind11`.

Binding was done like so:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(random_vectors, m) {
    py::class_<RandomVectorGenerator>(m, "random_vectors")
    .def(py::init<int, int>())
    .def("__iter__", [](RandomVectorGenerator &generator) {py::gil_scoped_release release;
        return py::make_iterator(generator.generator.begin(), generator.generator.end());
        },
         py::keep_alive<0, 1>());
};
```

Code above compiled and was used in python like so:

```py
from random_vectors import random_vectors

rv = random_vectors(15,10)

iterator = iter(rv)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Running it from terminal with `-X dev` resulted in segmentation error, line 7 being `iterator = iter(rv)`:

```bash
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f8c889f1740 (most recent call first):
  File "path-to-scrip/test.py", line 7 in <module>

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

This happened every time when it was executed from terminal, however, very rarely running it in Spyder 5.1.5 on Python 3.9.12 it worked and provided the expected output. The way this happened was very inconsistent, but my observation was this:

1. Try running it once in a fresh console
2. It fails and restarts kernel
3. Restart kernel manually
4. Very rarely it started working in said console

Another observation was that the process of trial and error caused temporary freezing and unresponsiveness. I also would like to note that it never worked in my actual application, which is much more complex.